# Reading shared memory from c++/c# program in java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, shared-memory, jna

How can I read a shared memory section like 
"Global\something_something"
in java that was created and is updated by a c#/c++ program?
I found some tutorials, but they either work with "real files" or have some other additional stuff.
I know that I have to make native calls via jna, for example, to the windows api and use something like the openFileMapping function.

Are there tutorials I have missed or could someone give me a bit of example code?
Is using jna or jni the only way to that sort of thing in java?

Comment: Maybe you are completely right and should head for a JNI based solution implemented in some low-level language (C?)

Comment: Using a memory mapped file is the only way to do it in Java without additional native code. However, as long as you don’t call sync extensively, there is no difference between a “real” temporary file and any other means of creating shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you can obtain a pointer to the memory location, you can use JNA's `Pointer` methods to access the memory.  Alternatively you can create a [direct NIO Buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect(int)), which facilitates sharing memory between Java and native.

Any one of these methods should work equally well for sharing memory.

```
// Use JNA-allocated non-Java heap memory
Memory m = new Memory(size);
myNativeLib.useSharedMemory(m);
// Use JVM-allocated non-Java heap memory
Buffer b = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
myNativeLib.useSharedMemory(b);
// Use native-allocated memory
Pointer p = myNativeLib.getSharedPointer();
```

If you want to share more than available physical memory, then you'd be better off using a [file-based mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).

**EDIT**

Addressing the specific question of accessing a Windows block of [Named Shared Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to understand how to access it via w32 APIs and then access those APIs via JNA (or JNI, if you prefer).

From the MS Docs:

```
   HANDLE hMapFile;
   LPCTSTR pBuf;

   hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
                   FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
                   FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
                   szName);               // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not open file mapping object (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());
      return 1;
   }

   pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
               FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
               0,
               0,
               BUF_SIZE);

   if (pBuf == NULL)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
             GetLastError());

      CloseHandle(hMapFile);

      return 1;
   }
```

It's a straightforward matter to map these functions into JNA for use in Java:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface MyKernel32 extends Kernel32 {
    int FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS = // look it up
    MyKernel32 INSTANCE = (MyKernel32)Native.loadLibrary(MyKernel32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    HANDLE OpenFileMapping(int dwDesiredAccess, boolean bInheritHandle, String lpName);
}
```

Note that JNA's `Kernel32` (in `platform.jar`) already includes a mapping for `MapViewOfFile`, which returns a `Pointer`.  Using that returned value, you can read and write to the shared memory to your heart's content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still a bit lost.  I have an application A, which I don't have the source to, which creates a shared memory section called "Global\application_A" and updates the data in there every second (it's not a lot of data, only a few kb). Now I want to create an application B in java, which reads that shared memory of A to print it to the console for example. It doesn't need write access to it, only read.

Comment: Please link to details of the definition of "shared memory section".  Perhaps you're referring to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Yes I think so. When I look at the process with the sysinternal process explorer and display the handles, the "Global\application_A" appears as "Section" and in its properties says "A memory mapped file of paging-file backed memory region" as description. I also can see the address there like "0xFFFFC00203422520", although I don't think that helps.