# Shared memory between Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, shared-memory, mmap

I'm trying to create some memory in C++ and access it in Java.
On the C++ side I know that I can use `shm_open` and `mmap` to obtain a 
memory region and write some data into it. But, how can I open the
memory-mapped file on the Java side? Someone suggested to use `MappedByteBuffer`
but how can that access the "path" provided to `shm_open` (it only exists in memory so cannot initialize a `File` from it). Can I do this without using JNI?

Comment: The functions you mention seem to indicate a Linux environment. Is that so? Or do you require more portable solution? Anyway, I suggest using more well established interprocess communication. Why not just use sockets.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440527/reading-shared-memory-from-c-c-program-in-java

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes it's linux environment. Doesn't have to be portable.  We want to use shared memory for performance reason (to avoid copying).

Comment: @BevynQ seems like the link you posted doesn't solve my issue. It's also windows based.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux environment shared memory has special memory segment:

`/dev/shm`

Name provided in shm_open (e.g. "elo320") is used to create file

`/dev/shm/elo320`

This path can be used in Java.